# Simple android application to prevent the use of camera

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

As the title stated, I want to design simple application without interaction from the user. After installation it will block the camera. then start a timer to release it after some time.

I tried 2 options: device manager using set camera disabled method but I could not run the project because of some errors in the manifast.

now I'm trying just to create a camera object to reserve the camera from other applications. but still the native camera app was able to start the camera.

My question: is my method correct? or there are much simpler ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

> device manager using set camera disabled method but I could not run the project because of some errors in the manifast.

Perhaps you should consider asking a separate Stack Overflow question where you explain what you tried and  what **specific** problems you encountered. If by "device manager" you mean the device administration APIs, this is the proper way of implementing what you want.

> is my method correct?

No.

Comment: Thanks, actually I managed to do it using (device manager API)